# Tensorflow: Multiplying tensor by 1 change the result significantly

Tags: tensorflow

Replacing a tensor `t` in my model by `t*1` change numerical behavior significantly, and causes nans to propagate to the loss.
Before I take this to github issues, I was wondering if someone know a workaround for this "magic".

I am using version 1.0